# How to make a linking line in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Can I get help on how to make the dots link together upon User touch like the in the following Picture ?

[the line is connecting the 3 dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LlFa.png)

Comment: When you ask a question, it is important you provide the code you tried. This would tell what you have achieved and your coding level. This way you can be provided with appropriate help.

Comment: you can check this link, http://www.thegamecontriver.com/2015/05/how-to-draw-line-on-screen-in-unity-csharp.html, anyway please look at how to ask better question in stackoverflow here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are familiar with touch. all you have to do is use Line Renderer in unity. just go through this link  [Line Renderer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bqcu94VuVOI)